# Agregar tabla existente a proyecto ASP.NET Core - EF Core Database First

Tags: c#, asp, asp.net-core

Yo trabajo con aplicaciones muy viejas dando mantenimiento y estoy metiendome con asp.net core.

Quiero realizar un proyecto usando la base de datos existente que tiene cientos de tablas pero no quiero usar todas por lo que CODE FIRST no es lo que busco.

La opción que necesito es la de DATABASE FIRST pero no quiero que mapee toda la base de datos ya que generaría mucho código basura y que no ocupo ya que no quiero todas las tablas. Realizando un ejemplo puedo hacer el scaffold y con la propiedad -tables puedo especificar las tablas que quiero importar al proyecto.por ejemplo:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;"  
 -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
 -OutputDir Models -Context NorthwndContext 
 -Tables Products,Categories,Suppliers -Force
```

Hasta ahi todo bien, pero que pasa si más adelante necesito agregar una o más tablas que ya se encuentran en la base de datos y no las importe al inicio del proyecto, como se haría en ese caso ese es mi problema.

No se si mi búsqueda esta mal pero no encuentro un ejemplo que me ayude con esa parte por lo que solicito ayuda si alguien sabe como solucionar mi duda.

Gracias

Comment: Has probado a realizar otro `Scaffold-DbContext` con las nuevas tablas?

Comment: Hola Rafael, no se si seras el mismo del blog que encontré ayer que me ha ayudado mucho, al hacer otra vez scaffold-DbContext tengo que hacerlo con - force? Para sobreescribir archivod existentes. Saludos

Comment: Que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente?, importar más tablas sin que se sobreescriba lo que ya tienes hecho?

Comment: Exactamente eso, osea si ya tengo 3 tablas pero luego quiero agregar otras 3 que ya existan en la base de datos osea ir escalando poco a poco ya que son tantas tablas que la idea no es importar todo ya que generaría demasiado código que siento no puedo controlar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una buena pregunta la tuya.

Efectivamente, la herramienta `Scaffold-DbContext` de Entity Framework Core te permite realizar operaciones de Ingeniería Inversa sobre una BD existente (Database First) de **una solo vez**, o sea, **no** es una herramienta **incremental** con la que puedas ir creando los Modelos de tu aplicación según los vayas necesitando.

Aun así, **si es posible** realizar lo que tú necesitas mediante el uso de **clases parciales**.

Si te das cuenta las cuenta, las clases (Modelos y DbContext) que se auto-generan son del tipo **`partial`**. Esto quiere decir que se pueden extender (en otros archivos) sin necesidad de modificar el original.

---

**Clases parciales:**

Si tenemos la Clase `MiClase` en el archivo **MiClase.cs**:

```
partial class MiClase
{
    public int MiPropiedad_1 { get; set; }
    public void MiMetodo_1()
    {

    }
}
```

Podemos extenderla sin modificarla, en el archivo **MiClaseExtendida.cs** de la siguiente manera:

```
partial class MiClase
{
    public int MiPropiedad_2 { get; set; }
    public void MiMetodo_2()
    {

    }
}
```

Vemos que le hemos añadido una propiedad y un método nuevos, sin "tocar" la Clase original.

---

Volviendo al `Scaffold-DbContext`, cuando queramos añadir nuevos Modelos (tablas) a nuestra aplicación, debemos regenerar **todo el contexto de nuevo** con `-force`, **sobrescribiendo** todo lo que había antes.

Ahora, si por cualquier cosa necesitamos modificar los Modelos o el DbContext que ya tenemos generados, debemos hacerlo mediante **clases parciales** y en **archivos diferentes** a los que auto-genera el `Scaffold-DbContext`.

Así de esta manera, tendremos siempre una estructura **generada automáticamente** por `Scaffold-DbContext` que **nunca modificaremos a mano**. y por otro lado las modificaciones que queramos en clases parciales de otros archivos.

Answer (score 0):

Me he topado con el mismo problema y lo que yo hago es simplemente agregar el nombre de la tabla que quiero agregar, pero sin olvidar las que ya se encuentran generadas. Es decir:

> Scaffold-DbContext
>   "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;"
>   -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer   -OutputDir Models -Context NorthwndContext   -Tables Products,Categories,Suppliers, NUEVA_TABLA, NUEVA_TABLA2 -Force

Espero te se útil, a mí me ha funcionado perfectamente, saludos

Comment: Es una buena opción, pero por que dices de las tablas "*pero sin olvidar las que ya se encuentran generadas*", si no las incluyes que pasa?. Y por otra parte, que ocurre con tu DbContext, se sobrescribe?.

Comment: practicamente estas sobrescribiendo todos los modelos, asi como el contexto. Sobre no olvidar los modelos o tablas ya generadas, si llegas a olvidar alguna posiblemente pierdas esta referencia.

Answer (score 0):

Al realizar:
`PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context NorthwndContext -Tables Products,Categories,Suppliers, NUEVA_TABLA, NUEVA_TABLA2 -Force`

Vuelves a generar de nuevo lo **modelos** y el archivo **NorthwndContext**, pierdes todos los cambios que haya realizado en ambos archivos, por ejemplo en los modelos tenias :
`[Required(ErrorMessage = "Usuario requerido")] [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "EL {0} debe ser mínimo de {2} y máximo {1} caracteres", MinimumLength = 5)] [Display(Name = "usuario")]`
Todos estos cambios se perderan y el modelo quedara como al inicio cuando realizas el `Scaffold-DbContex` por primera vez, este método te funciona perfecto si no haz modificado los **modelos** y **NorthwndContext** que se generón.

http://vbpuntonet.blogspot.com/